# Access is denied while trying to install the 'Apache2.4' service using httpd.exe -k install

Tags: windows, apache, permissions, access-denied, apache2.4

I'm unable to install 'Apache2.4' as a service on Windows 11 using the command

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

I tried it on Command Prompt (as an admin) and on Windows Powershell (as an admin), but all I'm getting is the following error (see image in the link).

[Access is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMTXG.png)

Has anyone had the same problem? I tried following other guides online (either on forums or other Stack Overflow answers), but haven't been able to solve it yet?

I tried changing the permissions of the httpd.exe file to full permissions; executed the command

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

multiple times both on Windows Powershell and Command Prompt.
I also check if previous versions were installed, but none were found.